# Email not being sent to all users with deliver_later

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, actionmailer, sidekiq, rails-activejob

I am iterating over an array of subscriber ids to send each subscriber an email, but for some reason not all subscribers are getting the email.

Here is the controller calling the model method:

```
class Admin::EmailDigestsController < ApplicationController
    def send_digest
        article_ids = params[:article_ids]
        subject = params[:subject]
        EmailDigest.send_email_digest(article_ids, subject)

        redirect_to email_digests_path
    end
end
```

And here is email_digest.rb:

```
class EmailDigest < ActiveRecord::Base

    def self.send_email_digest(article_ids, subject)
        subscribers = EmailDigest.where.not(status: "Inactive").ids

        subscribers.each do |subscriber|
          DigestMailer.weekly_digest(subscriber, article_ids, subject).deliver_later
        end
    end

end
```

And here is digest_mailer.rb:

```
class DigestMailer < ActionMailer::Base
   default from: "secret@secret.com"

    def weekly_digest(subscriber, article_ids, subject)

        @subscriber = EmailDigest.find_by_id(subscriber)
        @subject = subject
        articles_arr = []
        article_ids.each do |f|
          articles_arr << Article.find_by_id(f)
        end
        @articles = articles_arr

         mail(to: @subscriber.email,
         subject: subject)
    end
end
```

I also have sidekiq set up and it works sufficiently to send at least one email, but perhaps there is something wrong with the way errors are handled.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Do your logs show it being sent? Attempted to be sent? do you have access to the mail server logs.

Comment: @Doon no i don't. Using Zoho mail and app deployed on Heroku.

Comment: have you tried deliver_now just to check if the mails are sended? What is the spam score of your mails? probably the mails are blocked. How have you configured actionmailer?

Comment: The following code `EmailDigest.where.not(status: "Inactive").ids` filters out any users whose status is 'inactive'. Could that be it?

Comment: deliver_now sends the emails. And yes, I am referring only to subscribers without "Inactive" status.